# Changing format of table

Tags: excel

I am pulling data from a database application and the format the data is in is not what I want it to be. This is how the data is currently formatted:

[image]

This is how I want it to be:

[image]

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide us with some of the code you have tried and what database you are using?

Comment: You could do this with VBA or Power Query.  You might be able to do it with formulas, but it would be more complicated.  Please show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your first cell "Nominal Date: 04/01/2021" is in cell B2, place this formula in cell A2:

```
=IF(LEFT(B2,14)="Nominal Date: ",DATE(RIGHT(B2,4),MID(RIGHT(B2,10),4,2),LEFT(RIGHT(B2,10),2)),A1)
```

Then:

- drag it to the end of the list;
- copy-paste the values;
- delete column D (the one with the "Hol");
- sort the list according to column B (the one with names);
- search for the rows with nominal dates and delete them.

You can also record a macro while doing it. Then you can go into VBA, read the code, refine it and improve it. If something goes wrong and you can't make it work properly, try to identify the problem, search for a solution and if you can't come up with one, come back and ask another question. We will be glad to help.